# How to bind data to the DropDown list within a kendo UI Gridview in an MVC 5.0 web application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I am suppose to develop a mvc 5.0 view with a Kendo UI gridview control for [employee details] - one of the column in this gridview will be a kendo ui dropdown list for [work status] field. Our application layers are like this [Views -> WebAPI -> Repository -> Models -> EntityFramework - DB].

What I have to achieve is:

1. is to populate the [work status] dropdownlist (within that gridview) consuming a Web API method.
2. the dropdown list should display the current [work status] of the employee as selected value
3. the dropdown list should be realtime editable - the user can click the dropdown list and change the employees [workstatus] to something else
4. the new [work status] should be automatically saved (without clicking a save button).

I am refering to a link on telerik site - I know this is how I am suppose to do it. The link is : [Telerik Kendo UI Grid](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-client-template-using-razor-mvc)

My issues:

1. I am able to put a dropdown list in the gridview control - however it is not populating - I suppose I am not getting the .DataSource() part of the dropdown correct (The datat source will be a web api method).
2. After populating the dropdown list with all the available [work status] - how to set the selected [work status] from the employee's current work status?
3. How to make the gridview editable without clicking a button in real time
4. after the new [work status] is selected how to save it using webapi (without a save button click).

I am new to MVC - and very new to WebAPI and have never used Telerik controls before.